# Can Android Actionbar be placed vertically?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I want to have an action bar placed vertically(Tablet App)

[image: Vertically placed action bar]

Can I have this? I know the default action bar does not support this.

Can sherlock action bar?

Can any other?

I have given this time but I dont see any solution to this.

Comment: there is no vertical actionbar in Android Design Guidelines, what's the point for doing that? you want sth like slide menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can sherlock action bar?

No. It backports what's available in the built-in `ActionBar`.

> Can any other?

AFAIK no library provides such functionality.

> Can I have this?

Of course you can. Depending on what you use from `ActionBar` this could be easy. On The image you have provided there is a `FrameLayout` with two `Buttons` and additionally hidden overlay `ListView` after pressing bottom `Button`. Not too much work.

Comment: This style is quite like [CommonsWare's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) style of answering (the +1 isn't for that. it's for providing an alternative ;-) ).

Comment: Thanks. Though I really do not understand how can they not allow this. What is there to be so strict about it!

Comment: @user2156936 It's not that they do not allow this. It's just that they didn't think it is such a good idea. It would be harder for user to read vertical text (title, tabs). There are also alternatives that you could try, like Navigation Drawer or Sliding Pane from the support library.

Comment: @MaciejGórski: Can you please elaborate more. I got the similar requirement from my client and he is also looking for vertical action bar.